# Why are apps unregistered in App Check (beta) of project settings of a firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

**App Check (beta)** of project settings of a firebase project is showing apps as unregistered, but it is not showing how to solve it. I added my apps' package name and debug SHA-1 key in this project. I have also used Google authentication in my app. Now, how can I register my app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because those apps are not currently set up for App Check. If you click on the field, it'll prompt you for one of several verification means of attestation. Setting this service up and implementing it within your app's source code will register the app within App Check.

You can find the documentation for the respective attestations [**here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check)

Comment: Do I need to download the google-services.json file again and paste that in my projects app folder after adding the SHA-256 key in App Check option?

Comment: no, all you need to do is add the key to the Recaptcha method when you initiate your firebase app as well